# When word merging is introduced, will the data I pre-populate be editable?

Tags: cognito-forms

If so, while I don't anticipate the ability to write to the distant file, would my "entries" report be able to show if the pre-populated data has been edited so I can go into my other system and make the necessary changes?

Answer (score 1):

Our upcoming PDF/Word merge feature will create rich custom documents based on the data from the form.  These documents will not be connected to the form data once they are generated, but will be editable with appropriate software, like Microsoft Word or Adobe Acrobat.

If changes are made to entries in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), these documents can be easily regenerated to reflect the changes.  Please send us a support request if you are interested in participating in our private beta for this feature!